# How do I use Get-EventLog to get the same result of Get-WinEvent in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2003

I am working on Windows Server 2003 and I need to get something like the following by using this command `Get-WinEvent -ListLog Application, Security, System`

```
LogMode   MaximumSizeInBytes RecordCount LogName
-------   ------------------ ----------- -------
Circular            33554432       15188 Application
Circular           201326592      298459 Security
Circular            33554432       10074 System
```

I need the result of the property `MaximumSizeInBytes` but `Get-WinEvent` is not supported on Server 2003

I see that `Get-EventLog` has a property called `MaximumKilobytes` but the result I get is different

I would like to know if there is a command can be ran locally to get the same result

Comment: have you tried running `Get-WinEvent` on a different system that does support it ... and using the `-ComputerName` parameter to access the remote system?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yea it works but I want to get that info by using a command locally

Comment: i have no ideas on that. [*sigh ...*] however, if your requirement is that this be run locally, you should add that to your Question so that others will understand the needs involved. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for the suggestion, just edited it :)

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to help a little bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no one has provided a satisfying answer yet I will just post the answer I found online [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-check-the-size-of-my-event-log-and-then-backup-and-archive-it-if-it-is-more-than-half-full/). The following command saved my life:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NTEventLogFile | Select-Object -Property MaxFileSize, LogfileName, Name, NumberOfRecords
```

I will not choose my own answer as the final answer just yet so if you can think of a better solution please feel free to add it :)

Thank you for viewing my post and tried to help

Answer (score 1):

First why are you still on WS2K3?  --- ;-}
Before you respond, I know, I know, some orgs... right!?  ;-}

Yet, unless someone on this site has WS2K3, there is no way for them to validate stuff.

This cmdlet not supported on WS2K3 is not a bug or missing thing. cmdlets are OS version and PowerShell version specific.

All that being said. Just because a command does not exist on your system, does not mean you cannot try use it.

This is why implicit PSRemoting exists.

[Remoting the Implicit Way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/remoting-the-implicit-way)

[Using implicit PowerShell remoting to import remote modules](https://4sysops.com/archives/using-implicit-powershell-remoting-to-import-remote-modules)

Mostly you see this used for ADDS, Exchange, O365 cmdlets and the like, but you can do it for any module / cmdlet on a remote host to use on your local session. Using implicit remoting the cmdlet really does not run on your system it is proxied. Just be sure to use the -prefix argument so to not end up with duplicate cmdlets being listed.

Example

```
$RemoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName 'RemoteHost' -Credential (Get-Credential -Credential "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME")
Import-PSSession -Session $RemoteSession -Prefix RS
```

So, no you call the cmdlets using the prefix when you want to use one from that session.

```
Get-RSWinEvent
```

Now, as I said, I have no WS2K3 boxes to mess with as I am all WS2K12R2/16/19. Yet, give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!! Sorry I cannot choose this as the answer as I specifically said in my post that I will need a local command but not through a remote session :(